# Datatable Editor's "new" form posts empty values

Tags: ajax, forms, laravel, datatables, editor

after one week of search/tests/debugging and headaches... I'm kindly seeking your help on the following problem: Consider the following simple piece of code (I'm focusing on the POST only):

```
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: {
        create: {
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/employees'
        },
        edit: {
            type: 'PUT',
            url:  'XXXXXXXX'
        },
        remove: {
            type: 'DELETE',
            url:  'XXXXXXXX'
        }
    },
    table: "#example",
    fields: [ {
            label: "First name:",
            name: "first_name"
        }, {
            label: "Last name:",
            name: "last_name"
        }, {
            label: "Position:"
            name: "position"
        }
    ]
} );

$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: "/employees",
    columns: [
        { data: "first_name" },
        { data: "last_name" },
        { data: "position" },
    ],
    select: true,
    buttons: [
        { extend: "create", editor: editor },
        { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
        { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
    ]
} );
```

When I submit the form, it posts empty values for the 3 fields! Do I need to serialize Editor's form fields?

I'm using Laravel as PHP MVC The related "#example" datatables displays data correctly, no problem on that.
I just want to use the client side Datatable...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the form is posting values... However I get them as "urlencode" and can't use them in my controller... Will post another question...